# EEA family permit & EEA National Registration Certificate Number

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu, eu-citizens, eu-spouses

[image]Good day all.

I am polish national living in UK. My wife is about to  apply for an EEA FP to join me. In the application they ask for my EEA National Registration Certificate Number, I do not have this as I have only been in the UK just over 3 months. Now the question is,do I have to have this or can she still apply without there being any problems? Can we just put N/A in that part of the application?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pdf application](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270530/vaf5.pdf), which you are [probably not using](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/apply), actually asks for

> 8.1.11 EEA National Registration Certificate number (if held)

This clearly indicates that the certificate number is not mandatory.  It's not mandatory because the certificate itself is not mandatory; the guidance at the end of the file reads:

> 8.1.11 EEA National Registration Certificate number (if held)
>   This is a certificate that confirms the EEA National’s residence in
>   the UK. It is not compulsory to hold this certificate. The number
>   is in the top right hand corner and is in the following format UK
>   X1234567.

I suspect that the better course of action is to leave this item blank, but if that is not acceptable for any reason, N/A is probably the second best response.

Comment: Thank you for that but that's the old form am not to sure how I can upload a picture an here but the form for EEA Family Permit has changed and they have refused the visa to some people on that grounds

Comment: @Maciej you can upload a picture using the "image" button at the top of the edit box -- it looks like a little mountain with a small moon or sun in the upper right corner.  The PDF form is apparently only for people applying from North Korea, but the requirements around national registration certificates have not changed.

Comment: OK I added the screenshot the question is not before the last.

Comment: @Maciej I filled out this form a little over a year ago, and I found it extremely frustrating and poorly designed.  I did not enter a certificate number for that application, but the EEA national was not resident in the UK.  Still, the fact remains that the registration certificate is not required, so, since the field is a required field, and you have no certificate, you should probably enter "None" or "N/A" or the like.

Comment: To clarify, by "poorly designed" I mean to refer to the conditional and validation logic.  So in your case the certificate number should not be required.  In my case, the form was asking whether the EEA national and non-EEA applicant had ever been married or whether they had children together, when the application was for a dependent parent.  The paper application properly directs the applicant to skip such questions, but the online version incorrectly presented these questions and required responses.

Comment: That is so true regarding ::poorly designed'' it is just frustrating. One of the questions ask what are you living expenses for the UK when you not even living there.  And some questions are poorly worded eg when asking for the EEa's address they don't ask what is the EEa's ae but what is your address making you think the want the address of the person filling out the form... Anyways thank you very much. You help alot.. Is there any way I can message you privately if I have any other questions or can I just give you my wives email so she can speak with you??

Comment: @Maciej I'm more likely to see messages here than in my e-mail.  I don't check it that often.  You can try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here), but if you have additional questions, it's probably better to post them as new questions.  It's a question and answer site, after all.

Comment: @Maciej I accidentally gave the link for travel chat.  The Expats chat is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13567/the-embassy.