# EEA National registration certificate number

Tags: uk-visa, italian-citizens

My civil partner is making an application to move to the UK and be with me. I live in the UK and I have an Italian passport. I am self-employed but I don't have an EEA National Registration Number. I am here legally, exercising my rights, and have had no issues. I have an NI number, company, insurance etc. I pay council tax and so on.

Now the form is asking her for my EEA National Registration Number, which I don't have, and it won't let her progress in the application unless she puts something in there starting with an 'X'. Has anyone had this problem and actually solved it? Do I need to make this EEA registration number application? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What form is she filling out?

Comment: She s filling out an EEA Family Permit

Comment: At which site?  If it's not at https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/, she's filling out the wrong form.  In any event, you're not required to have the certificate for her to get the permit.

Comment: I just filled out an application there and put "none" for the certificate number; it allowed me to get to the next page.  It also allowed me to "confirm" the application.  I did not actually submit it, however.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for the info. We just put my N.I number in the box. Someone advised us at the embassy to do that. I will wait to make my application until she gets here. It also appears that they want my original passport which would prove to be a problem since I need it to work.

Comment: She can submit a certified copy of your passport.  See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for your help its much appreciated

Comment: See also [EEA family permit & EEA National Registration Certificate Number](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8284/2440).

Answer (score 1):

When I filled out an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) application for my mother in law, with my wife as the EEA national, we supplied "none" for the registration certificate number.

If you apply for a registration certificate along with your wife's [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) application, you will be able to use the European passport return service, which seems like the least stressful way to proceeed, especially as you note in a comment that you need your passport for work.  But even then, she can get her residence card without your getting a residence certificate.

If you've been in the UK for over five years, you might want to get a [certificate of permanent residence](https://www.gov.uk/eea-registration-certificate/permanent-residence), as that will possibly give you greater rights when the UK leaves the EU.

Comment: note that (as of 5/6/2018) the certificate of permanent residence will be explicitly void once Britain leaves the EU - and there's nothing to replace it yet. The only reason you might want to obtain that if you wish to apply for citizenship (before Brexit), as it's a prerequisite

Comment: @SztupY do you have a government source with that information?

Comment: yep it's on gov.uk: https://www.gov.uk/eea-registration-certificate/permanent-residence "If you already have a permanent residence document it won’t be valid after the UK leaves the EU." The new "settlement" status will take it's place but it hasn't been approved or voted on.

Comment: @SztupY given that "A new scheme will be available for EU citizens and their family members to apply to stay in the UK after it leaves the EU," and the details of that scheme are, as you note, unknown, there's another reason to get a certificate: it might be helpful to establish one's eligibility for the replacement scheme.  It just as well might not be helpful for that purpose, of course, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: the UK strongly insisted during the EU talks that the PR is completely useless post-Brexit, so I'm still unsure whether a PR cert is useful at this stage unless you actually need it before Brexit. Also the new status are said to be much easier to obtain than a PR (e.g. no requirement to have health insurance if you're not a worker). The only thing the EU insisted that obtaining settlement status should be free if you already have a PR, but we don't know whether a PR status would be enough on it's own when filling out the settlement status form, as we don't yet know how it will look like

Comment: @SztupY I believe what they meant is that it would not directly demonstrate a right to be in the UK.  It would certainly continue to be useful to demonstrate that the UK had determined that such a right had existed before Brexit.  What about those who have a right of permanent residence but never sought the document?  Will they be eligible for the new status?  If that question has not yet been answered, then seeking the document is very likely to be a good idea.  However I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to by "the UK strongly insisted..."; can you link to something?

Comment: given the current Windrush scandal I'm more on the sceptical side on any immigration related stuff. I remember the anti-PR view from the UK government was raised during last year's EU talks - but can't find an official link yet. In any case I still don't think there's a point of getting a PR if the new status will be 1. easier to obtain 2. cost the same, or maybe less 3. is going to be a real proof of right to be in the UK - unless obviously you need that PR status for other reasons than a right to residency before Brexit (naturalization, family permits, etc.)