# EEA Family Permit - EEA National registration certificate number

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu, uk-visa, eu-spouses

My wife is making an EEA Family Permit application to move to the UK. She is doing the application through visa4uk.fco.gov.uk. My wife is from Asia. I live in the UK and I have a Dutch passport. I am working in the UK (permanent job) but I don't have an EEA National Registration Number.

Now the form is asking her for my EEA National Registration Number, which I don't have. This is a mandatory field in the application. Has anyone had this problem and actually solved it? Do I need to make this EEA registration number application? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As you can see from the linked question, you're not the first to have this problem.  You should not need to get an EEA registration number for the EEA family permit.  I believe that you *will* need to get it if your wife applies to stay in the UK, but if you apply together she can use the European Passport Return Service.  (On the other hand, it seems that with Brexit registering as an EEA national may have very little benefit.)

Comment: Another duplicate: [EEA National registration certificate number](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/13520/2440)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Although there are many posts on this topic, no 
  proper answer to the question. In the online form, the Registration number is mandatory, I cannot skip that. I don't know what to put

Comment: Just put "none" or "n/a"